# GNU Radio prerequisite libraries on armhf

Tags: ubuntu, repository, arm

After several attempts, I have managed to compile GNURadio on the Raspberry Pi. However, I am just not able to meet the prerequisites for the [gnuradio build script](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/InstallingGR#Using-the-build-gnuradio-script) on the Pandaboard (Linaro 12.04) or the BeagleBoard (Ubuntu 12.04)

This is what I see -

```
Failed to find package 'libqwtplot3d-qt4-dev' in known package repositories
Perhaps you need to add the Ubuntu universe or multiverse PPA?
see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu
exiting build
```

I have tried adding all kinds of repositories to get this to work. What repository do I get `libqwtplot3d-qt4-dev` from for the armhf architecture? Can I mix armfh and armel packages?

Comment: Re "Can I mix armfh and armel packages?" -- http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/60282/4319

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That package isn't int the Ubuntu repositories for `armel` or `armhf` (at least according to [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/libqwtplot3d-qt4-dev) -- you can probably compile the source package (`qwtplot3d`). It looks like that package is in `universe`, so you'll need that enabled.

You should be able to run

```
apt-get build-dep qwtplot3d
apt-get source qwtplot3d
cd qwtplot3d-*/
dpkg-buildpackage
```

and get `.deb`s for what you need.

(If the last step fails, then the package needs some porting to work/compile on ARM -- either go nuts, or abandon all hope, depending on how much C++-fu you've got at the moment).

Comment: This mostly worked :-( The last step did not though! I get some errors of redifined data types and pointers that cannot be converted!

Comment: @Community: oops. I had not seen the edit and forked this question into a new question. ( http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55121/compiling-libqwplot3d-on-armhf )

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, however as I am interested to run some C++ scripts using gnuradio platform in pandaboard, I disabled 'libqwtplot3d-qt4-dev' pckg dependency in gnuradio build script. After this step I installed successfully GNU Radio.

Until this time GNU Radio is working ok to me.

I have tested some basic examples in GNU Radio Companion and it works OK.

[image]