# Compiling libqwplot3d on armhf

Tags: compiling

This started as an attempt to [compile GNURadio on armhf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53647) (Pandaboard & Beagleboard). Thanks to [the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53690/8496) by [Mike Larsen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/26755/mike-larsen). I tried to compile libqwplot3d.

```
apt-get build-dep qwtplot3d
apt-get source qwtplot3d
cd qwtplot3d-*/
dpkg-buildpackage
```

And get the following result in the last step:

```
user@lord-xm:~/qwtplot3d-0.2.7+svn191$ dpkg-buildpackage
dpkg-buildpackage: export CFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security
dpkg-buildpackage: export CPPFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
dpkg-buildpackage: export CXXFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security
dpkg-buildpackage: export FFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: export LDFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro
dpkg-buildpackage: source package qwtplot3d
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 0.2.7+svn191-5ubuntu2
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Scott Kitterman <scott@kitterman.com>
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture armhf
 dpkg-source --before-build qwtplot3d-0.2.7+svn191
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh_testdir
dh_testroot
rm -f build-stamp
rm -rf build
dh_clean
 dpkg-source -b qwtplot3d-0.2.7+svn191
dpkg-source: info: using source format `3.0 (quilt)'
dpkg-source: info: building qwtplot3d using existing ./qwtplot3d_0.2.7+svn191.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: building qwtplot3d in qwtplot3d_0.2.7+svn191-5ubuntu2.debian.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: building qwtplot3d in qwtplot3d_0.2.7+svn191-5ubuntu2.dsc
 debian/rules build
dh_testdir
mkdir -p build/qt4
cp -Rl `ls . |grep -v build|grep -v debian` build/qt4
cd build/qt4 && qmake-qt4 qwtplot3d.pro && /usr/bin/make
WARNING: doc.path is not defined: install target not created

make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/qwtplot3d-0.2.7+svn191/build/qt4'
g++ -c -pipe -g -D_REENTRANT -Wall -W -fPIC -DQT_WEBKIT -DGL2PS_HAVE_ZLIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4/QtOpenGL -I/usr/include/qt4 -Iinclude -I/usr/X11R6/include -Itmp -o tmp/qwt3d_axis.o src/qwt3d_axis.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/GL/glu.h:38:0,
                 from include/qwt3d_openglhelper.h:11,
                 from include/qwt3d_types.h:26,
                 from include/qwt3d_drawable.h:7,
                 from include/qwt3d_label.h:10,
                 from include/qwt3d_axis.h:5,
                 from src/qwt3d_axis.cpp:1:
/usr/include/GL/gl.h:162:17: error: conflicting declaration âtypedef double GLdoubleâ
/usr/include/qt4/QtOpenGL/qgl.h:85:17: error: âGLdoubleâ has a previous declaration as âtypedef GLfloat GLdoubleâ
In file included from /usr/include/GL/gl.h:2085:0,
                 from /usr/include/GL/glu.h:38,
                 from include/qwt3d_openglhelper.h:11,
                 from include/qwt3d_types.h:26,
                 from include/qwt3d_drawable.h:7,
                 from include/qwt3d_label.h:10,
                 from include/qwt3d_axis.h:5,
                 from src/qwt3d_axis.cpp:1:
/usr/include/GL/glext.h:5327:19: error: conflicting declaration âtypedef ptrdiff_t GLintptrâ
/usr/include/GLES2/gl2.h:38:26: error: âGLintptrâ has a previous declaration as âtypedef khronos_intptr_t GLintptrâ
/usr/include/GL/glext.h:5328:19: error: conflicting declaration âtypedef ptrdiff_t GLsizeiptrâ
/usr/include/GLES2/gl2.h:39:26: error: âGLsizeiptrâ has a previous declaration as âtypedef khronos_ssize_t GLsizeiptrâ
In file included from include/qwt3d_types.h:26:0,
                 from include/qwt3d_drawable.h:7,
                 from include/qwt3d_label.h:10,
                 from include/qwt3d_axis.h:5,
                 from src/qwt3d_axis.cpp:1:
include/qwt3d_openglhelper.h: In function âbool Qwt3D::ViewPort2World(double&, double&, double&, double, double, double)â:
include/qwt3d_openglhelper.h:106:97: error: cannot convert âdouble*â to âGLdouble* {aka float*}â for argument â7â to âGLint gluUnProject(GLdouble, GLdouble, GLdouble, const GLdouble*, const GLdouble*, const GLint*, GLdouble*, GLdouble*, GLdouble*)â
include/qwt3d_openglhelper.h: In function âbool Qwt3D::World2ViewPort(double&, double&, double&, double, double, double)â:
include/qwt3d_openglhelper.h:122:95: error: cannot convert âdouble*â to âGLdouble* {aka float*}â for argument â7â to âGLint gluProject(GLdouble, GLdouble, GLdouble, const GLdouble*, const GLdouble*, const GLint*, GLdouble*, GLdouble*, GLdouble*)â
make[1]: *** [tmp/qwt3d_axis.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/qwtplot3d-0.2.7+svn191/build/qt4'
make: *** [build-stamp] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
user@lord-xm:~/qwtplot3d-0.2.7+svn191$
```

How do  fix this and proceed? I am using the Ubuntu 12.04 image for OMAP